# Normalise the histogram for three data sets in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='step', lw=2, color='blue', 
                   label='color _22')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(y, 50, normed=1, histtype='step', lw=2, color='red', 
                   label='color _20')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(z, 50, normed=1, histtype='step', lw=2, color='green', 
                   label='color _18')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

I want to normalize these three datasets. When I plot using the above script, I got a non-normalize plot. Please let me know what can I do to normalize.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using `normed=1`, which is the old parameter that now is called `density=True`. In the latest version, `normed` causes an error message; in the versions before, it generates a deprecation warning.

Anyway, with `normed=1` (or `density=True`) you already get a normalized histogram. Note that normalization here means: the total area equals to one. This relates to the bin widths: bin width times the sum of all bin heights equals to one.

You'll notice that the blue histogram is wider, and the peak of the green histogram absorbs the difference in width. So, both having effectively the same area (1) as the red histogram.

Alternatively, you could suggest another type of normalization where the histogram height is defined as a percentage of the highest bar. The code below shows how that could look like. To prevent needing to draw the histograms twice, `np.histogram` is used to calculate the bin values, which can be plotted via `plt.step`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import numpy as np

N = 1000
x = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0, 0.04, N), np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 10)])
y = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0, 0.06, N), np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 10)])
z = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0, 0.08, N), np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 10)])
for data, color, label in zip((x, y, z), ('b', 'r', 'g'), ('x', 'y', 'z')):
    hist, bins = np.histogram(data, 50)
    plt.step(bins, np.pad(hist, (1, 0)) / hist.max(), where='pre', lw=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, label=label)
plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that default the histogram bins take the range from `x.min()` to `x.max()` which gets divided it into equals parts (50 in the example). As the 3 data arrays don't have the same `min` and `max`, the boundaries are somewhat arbitrarily. You could set all these boundaries equal by providing an explicit `range=(-2, 2)` to either `plt.hist` or `np.histogram`. If you're only interested in the central part, you could set that range narrower.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `density=True` to `plt.hist` to get a normalized histogram. That is:

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, density=True,
                            histtype='step', lw=2, 
                            color='blue', label='color _22')
...
```

Comment: here it is same as when I pass normed=1 or density=True for both cases.